# Can't figure out why my JavaScript for loop only loops once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to get my for loop to print each characters of a string argument individually, but when I run code, it only prints the first character. I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't keep looping through.

Here is my code:

```
function reverse (param) {
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(param.charAt(i));
    }
}

reverse("Test");
```

Comment: You must post the code itself, not images

Comment: `param.length` instead of `arguments.length`

Comment: `arguments.length` -> `param.length` There is only a single argument so `arguments.length` is `1`

Answer (score 1):

This code is working as it should. `arguments` length is 1. To make it work as intented, you must use `param`'s length

```js
function reverse (param) {
  console.log(arguments)
    for (var i=1; i<=param.length; i++) {

        console.log(param.charAt(param.length - i)); //you need to correct here as well
    }

}
 reverse("Test");
```

On another note, you may make use of [`.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function as well. But it works on arrays. So you can do something like this:

```js
console.log("Test".split('').reverse().join(''))
```

Comment: @rma943 great. You may accept the answer if it helps/

Answer (score 0):

Because arguments just contains ["Test"], so arguments.length is 1

Answer (score 0):

Because you need length of param and not arguments.

```
function reverse (param) {
    for (var i=0; i<param.length; i++) {
        console.log(param.charAt(i));
    }
}

reverse("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function printLetters(string) {
    for (let letter of string) {
        console.log(letter);
    }
}
printLetters("test");
```

Here's how you print the letters to the console